# Akeneo is not loading

Tags: ubuntu, browser, localhost, akeneo

After installation akeneo it is not working

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/web
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com

 <Directory /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/web>
      Options FollowSymlinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/akeneo_error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/akeneo_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to open http://example.com in browser it is not running.

Any  guidance any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Akeneo is being loaded. Make a die or a breakpoint with XDebug in the next file:

```
/web/app.php
```

Before this lane

```
$response = $kerner->handle($request);
```

If works, the next step is debug the next function:

```
private function handleException
```

Located in the next path:

```
/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php
```

If something is wrong, the **$e** variable will give you information (is debugged with XDebug)

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWk1Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running locally, make sure you have the below entry in `/etc/hosts` file.

`127.0.0.1 example.com`